# Not reversing the data when update the one schema in sanity studio

Tags: javascript, json, schema, sanity

I have two schemas called "Project" and "Employee" in my Sanity studio. I want to establish a reference between them so that I can associate projects with employees and vice versa. I have successfully created an employee and added a project to it, and it works well. However, I'm facing an issue where the employee is not visible in the project, and it's also not showing up in the JSON object.

I'm relatively new to Sanity, and I would greatly appreciate your assistance in resolving this situation. I have attached the code and an image for your reference.

I have attached the code and image for your reference

**employee schema**

```
export default {
    name: 'employee',
    title: 'Employee',
    type: 'document',
    fields: [
        {
            name: 'projectName',
            title: 'Project Name',
            type: 'string',
            validation: (Rule) => Rule.required(),
        }, {
            name: 'code',
            title: 'Code',
            type: 'string'
        },
        {
            name: 'assignedProjects',
            type: 'array',
            title: 'Assigned Projects',
            of: [{ type: 'reference', to: [{ type: 'projects' }] }],
        },
    ]
}
```

**Project Schema**

```
export default {
    name: 'projects',
    title: 'Projects',
    type: 'document',
    fields: [
        {
            name: 'projectName',
            title: 'Project Name',
            type: 'string',
            validation: (Rule) => Rule.required(),
        },
        {
            name: 'assignedEmployees',
            type: 'array',
            title: 'Assigned Employees',
            of: [{ type: 'reference', to: [{ type: 'employee' }] }],
        }
    ]
}
```

**Here I added the project.**
[image: Here I added the project.]

**But here not updating. Employee array are empty!**

[image: But here not updated. Employee array are empty!]